# How can I change the default sbt temporary directory?

Tags: scala, sbt, default, temporary-directory

SBT (the scala's interactive build tool) writes in Linux its temporary files in the /tmp directory. How can I change the default temporary directory?

Comment: Which intermediate files? The only temporary files I see are the ones under the target folder. Do you mean those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of sbt are you using?

I'm asking because of this PR: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5289, which was merged for sbt 1.4.0.

I assume you are using an older version. If you have a reason to stick with the older version, consider setting the `java.io.tmpdir` system property.

If you are already on 1.4.0 or newer, then you'll need to tell us what files you are seeing written to `/tmp` under what conditions, since the PR implies that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: My version of sbt is older than 1.4.0. and I lost the write access to the /tmp directory. When I started the sbt I got an exception:
  `java.io.IOException: Permission denied
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2070)
  at sbt.StandardMain$$anonfun$initialGlobalLogging$1.apply(Main.scala:68))`
 but when I set  system property java.io.tmpdir to another directory it works. 
 Thanks.

Comment: @Seth Tisue On Windows 10, and sbt 1.4.6, I am seeing jar temporarily stored in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_XXXXXX\*.jar`, where `XXXXXX` appears to be some randomly generated alphanumeric string

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Mac

```
mkdir /home/user/temp
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/user/temp"
```

Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir /home/user/temp
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/user/temp"
```